# Hash Function to generate Hash Key from File Path

Tags: linux, operating-system, filesystems, hashtable, linode

Any ideas for a Hash Function to generate a Hask Key from file path name? I'd like to use this to maintain information about every file, as path for every file is unique, even if they have the same file name!

Answer (score 2):

you can use [openssl](http://linux.die.net/man/3/md5_init) hash functions, this is just an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <openssl/md5.h>    

int main()
{
  int i;
  unsigned char result[MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];
  const char *string = "path/to/file";

  MD5(string, strlen(string), result);

  // output
  for(i = 0; i < MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++)
    printf("%02x", result[i]);
  printf("\n");

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: How could that be used in a Hask key generating function in a program?!

Comment: @neo he didn't specify any programming language.

Comment: C, for example? If I'm writing a Hash function in C?